# Python Regex get Unique Multiline Matches

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, match, multiline

Since the background would be far to complicated to explain, I am writing Pseudocode,
I am only interested in the Python-Regex-Pattern, I hope one of you can help me

I have the folloing input text (lots of lines with `\n` as line seperator  condensed to '.'):

```
.
.
1 Order 
order1 stuff
order1 stuff
etc
ShippingMethod: Truck
.
.
2 Order
order2 stuff
order2 stuff
etc
ShippingMethod: Truck
.
.
Order Summary
.
.
```

I only want to match the texts in between 'Order' and 'Truck' **for each order indiviually**, I would then iterate over the results further along in the program.

my Regex: ( i am splitting into "start, content, end" for better readability).

`pattern = \d\s*Order + [.|\s|\S]* + Truck`

When I execute this match, i get one result, beginning at `1 Order` and stopping at the *second* `Truck`:

```
1 Order 
order1 stuff
order1 stuff
etc
ShippingMethod: Truck
.
.
2 Order
order2 stuff
order2 stuff
etc
ShippingMethod: Truck
```

I want (in this case) *exactly two* matches which only include one order's contents:

```
1 Order 
order1 stuff
order1 stuff
etc
ShippingMethod: Truck
```

```
2 Order
order2 stuff
order2 stuff
etc
ShippingMethod: Truck
```

I hope it's clear what I am looking for. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance, stay safe, stay healthy!


Things you might suggest:

- You have to assume varying amounts of Whitespaces at the start of a line and in between words, since the input text is the result of a PDF-text-extractor. But \n can be trusted. Basically insterad of writing \n write \s*\n
- I can't use "Order" as the end-part of the pattern, since after  the last order the next thing is a summary.
- "ShippingMethod" is different in my language, that's why I used "Truck" for this example here. I will manage to rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is deceptively simple - use the non-greedy operator `?`.

To begin with, the character class regex `[]` matches ANY character in it, so to match `a` and `b` the regex is `[ab]` and not `[a|b]`. So the *content* part of your code should be `[.\s\S]`.
Also, `\s` and `\S` match all spaces and non-spaces respectively, so the period (`.`) is irrelevant here.

So the final content part should look like this: `[\s\S]*`

## Now for the actual solution:

The greedy `?` operator after any normal frequency operator like `+`, `*` and `?` tells the regex to match **as few of the element/s as possible**. With `*`, you're using the default greedy version of *zero-or-more*, telling the regex to match as many as possible (which ends up matching even the first `Truck` you want!)

So we add a non-greedy operator at the end, so the final regex looks like this:

```
\d\s*Order[\s\S]*?Truck
```

---

## Bonus Advice:

The character class `[\s\S]` is a neat way to tell the regex to match EVERY CHARACTER (because every character is either a space or not a space). But it turns out there's a way to improve efficiency by using the `re.DOTALL` modifier. It does what it says - it tells the regex that `.` (the DOT) should match ALL characters, including newlines.

If this is the code you were using:

```
re.findall(r'\d\s*Order[\s\S]*?Truck', input_text)
```

Here's the best possible code (including the solution of the question):

```
re.findall(r'\d\s*Order.*?Truck', input_text, re.DOTALL)
```

As you can see, the `.*?` will now match everything (including newlines) from `Order` to `Truck`.

Comment: It just works. Thank you so much! Unfortunately i can't do the re.DOTALL trick, since the three parts of my regex are defined in an exernal CSV file. So hardcoding the behaviour might work for this information I want to extract but might be overkill for the next rule.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jXPEQvp - i use removeprefix and removesuffix to (not) include these parts to my results (0/1). There are five more colums - it's a beautiful monstrosity you contributed to haha.

Comment: Ahh nice catch, if you're using CSV then it's definitely smart to not use DOTALL.

Comment: Making beautiful monstrosities is the essence of coding lmao

Answer (score 0):

Without using re.DOTALL, and prevent overmatching if `Truck` is not present, you can use:

```
^\d+\s*Order\b.*(?:\n(?!\d+\s* Order\b|.* Truck$).*)*\n.* Truck$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+\s*Order\b.*` Match digits followed by `Order` and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?!\d+\s* Order\b|.* Truck$)` Match a newline and assert that the lines does not start with digits and `Order` and assert that the line does not end with `Truck`
  - `.*` If the assertion is true, match the whole line
- `)*` Close non capture group to match all lines
- `\n.* Truck$` Match a newline and the rest of the line that ends with `Truck`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eONAod/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SdFcw3)

```
import re
 
regex = r"^\d+\s*Order\b.*(?:\n(?!\d+\s* Order\b|.* Truck$).*)*\n.* Truck$"
 
s = ("\n\n"
    "1 Order \n"
    "order1 stuff\n"
    "order1 stuff\n"
    "etc\n"
    "ShippingMethod: Truck\n\n\n"
    "2 Order\n"
    "order2 stuff\n"
    "order2 stuff\n"
    "etc\n"
    "ShippingMethod: Truck\n\n\n"
    "Order Summary\n\n")
 
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['1 Order \norder1 stuff\norder1 stuff\netc\nShippingMethod: Truck', '2 Order\norder2 stuff\norder2 stuff\netc\nShippingMethod: Truck']
```

Comment: Thanks to you too, I hope I didn't steal you too much of your time because it already works just as intended. I just meant I would use re.DOTALL, but I want to put the maximum behaviour control into the CSV and not have it in the code. I might add another True/False column in the CSV and do a if/else in the code tho...